# redirect to PFsense IPsec tunnel endpoit which has public IP

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel, pfsense

I have got a working IPsec connection where the Remote subnet has a non internet IP address (105.x.y.z/25).

Trying to access this address of course leads to the public internet.

How can I redirect all request to  10X.x.y.z/25 to the IPSec tunnel (and within that to the Local Subnet of the connected side)?
(Of course the "real" 10X.x.y.z/25 addresses will not be reachable anymore.)

Comment: 105.x.y.z definitely looks like an Internet address to me?

Comment: Yes - but in this case it is used as address of IP-Sec Remote subnet (I have not chosen this - but I I need to use it.)